# Setting up FEST on Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, fest

I am trying to automate testing with FEST after having unsatisfactory results with UISpec4J. I am somewhat new to NetBeans and have to use 6.8 for the project that I am working with. I have written a test case using FEST and have downloaded the zip file from FEST's google code repository. I have tried setting the jar file under the properties library tab, but I am still having issues. I am unable to reference methods and classes from FEST.

Answer (score 0):

To fix my own problem, I ended up having to use an old snapshot of FEST instead of the zip file. I got the snapshot from my team members.